# Как вытащить текст ошибки в Python?

Tags: python-3.x

Использую requests для отправки запросов к серверу через прокси. Хочу обрабатывать как-то исключение, которое возникает в связи с неработоспособностью прокси. Ошибка выглядит так:

> HTTPConnectionPool(host='128.70.123.171', port=1080): Max retries exceeded with url (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',)))

Как можно вытащить из ошибки строку `ProxyError` или `Cannot connect to proxy`?

Answer (score 2):

```
try:
    r = requests.get(url,timeout=3)
    r.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
    print ("OOps: Something Else",err)
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
    print ("Http Error:",errh)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
    print ("Error Connecting:",errc)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
    print ("Timeout Error:",errt)
```

Выберите нужную ошибку, и обрабатывайте ее как надо...

Comment: стоит упомянуть, что у исключения атрибуты могут быть: `http_error.code`